# Python 3 script to fetch all google search results using xpath without selenium automation and without BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have tried the google custom search engine api but never gives me accurate results. I am try scrap all urls in google search result but after few requests google blocks me as a bot. Is there any way to fetch accurate results(almost)
I've tried the following code

```
import search_google.api
from apiclient.discovery import build

buildargs = {
        "serviceName": "customsearch",
        "version": "v1",
        "developerKey": "dkey"
            }
cseargs = {
       "q": "search",
       "cx": "ckey",
       "num": 8
          }
results = search_google.api.results(buildargs, cseargs)
#results.preview()

# Obtain the url links from the search
# Links are inside results['items'] list
links = results.get_values('items', 'link')

# Obtain the url links from the search
links = results.links
for a in links:
    print (links)

# Save the search result links to a text file
#  results.save_links('links.txt')



# Set developer key and CSE ID
dev_key = 'dkey'

cse_id = 'ckey'




# Obtain search results from Google CSE
service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=dev_key)

results = service.cse().list(q='infotek', cx=cse_id).execute()

#print("\n",results.get_values('items','link'))

#res = service.cse().list(q="keyword query", cx=my_cse_id, 
**kwargs).execute()
```

Comment: Are you trying to get help with incorrect responses? If so, how are the responses incorrect? Or are you asking to get help avoiding the rate-limiting?

Comment: Yes responses do not match with actual google search because google customizes search according to location and all but if there's any other alternative than this I am open to it I've also tried googlesearch package but it blocks me after few requests